# Remove a section of text from string c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using tags in a richtexteditor to specify data fields.

E.g [Start] and [End]

How can I remove a section of text between [Start] and [End] from a string block including the tags?

Is there an easier way rather than using IndexOf and Substring etc?

Update:
I'm attempting to use
var output = Regex.Replace("[Start]SomeText[End]", @"(?<=[Start]).*(?=[End])", "")

But the pattern does not quite work. It needs to remove everthing between [Start] and [End]

Comment: No easier way that I have found.

Comment: What kind of *easier way* you are looking for?

Comment: Adding to @huMptyduMpty, easier could mean one or more factors you should define: faster, less lines of code, readability, maintainability, scalability..

Comment: Using less lines of code and readability, Not knowing the full c# language, I wasn't sure if there was a nice function to assist with this in c#.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Regex to replace the text between [Start] and [End]. The following code snippet should help...

```
var output = Regex.Replace("[Start]SomeText[End]", @"(?<=\[Start\]).*(?=\[End\])", "");
```

Comment: I would be happy to help if you can tell me what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression, but I can't think of anything 'easier' than searching the file for it.